# Semi-definite program for smooth min-entropy

Tags: density-matrix, semidefinite-programming, matlab

The conditional min-entropy is defined as ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-entropy)):

$$
H_{\min}(A|B)_{\rho} \equiv -\inf_{\sigma_B}\inf_{\lambda}\{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}:\rho_{AB} \leq 2^{\lambda} \mathbb{I} \otimes \sigma_B\}
$$

And the smooth min-entropy is defined as:

$$
H_{\min}^{\epsilon}(A|B)_{\rho} \equiv \sup_{\rho'} H_{\min}(A|B)_{\rho'}
$$

Which just means that $\rho'_{AB}$ is some $\epsilon$-bounded distance away from $\rho_{AB}$. I know how to write a semi-definite program of the conditional min-entropy, which is:

$$
\text{min } \text{tr}(X) \\
\text{such that:} \\
\mathbb{I} \otimes X \ge \rho_{AB}\\
X \in \text{Herm}(\mathcal{H_B})
$$
I can implement this program in cvx(matlab). But the trouble is, in order to calculate the smooth min-entropy, I have to take a maximization over all $\rho'_{AB}$ who are $\epsilon$-distance away from $\rho_{AB}$. This means I need to write a double objective function in the semidefinite program. Something like:

$$
\text{max } \rho'_{AB} \\
\text{min } \text{tr}(X) \\
\text{such that:} \\
\mathbb{I} \otimes X \ge \rho'_{AB}\\
X \in \text{Herm}(\mathcal{H_B}) \\
\rho'_{AB} \in \mathcal{B}^\epsilon(\rho_{AB})
$$

What is the correct form of this double objective function? Is there any hope of writing it in cvx (matlab)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need a double objective function to solve this. Given $\rho_{AB}$ let $\rho_{ABC}$ be any purification of $\rho_{AB}$. Then we can write the smooth min-entropy as the following SDP
\begin{align*}
2^{-H_{\min}^{\epsilon}(A|B)} = \min& \quad\mathrm{Tr}(\sigma_B) \\
\text{s.t.}& \quad I_A \otimes \sigma_B \geq \mathrm{Tr}_C(\widetilde{\rho}_{ABC}) \\
& \quad \mathrm{Tr}(\widetilde{\rho}_{ABC}) \leq 1 \\
& \quad \mathrm{Tr}(\widetilde{\rho}_{ABC} \rho_{ABC}) \geq 1 - \epsilon^2 \\
& \quad \widetilde{\rho}_{ABC} \geq 0 \\
& \quad \sigma_B \geq 0
\end{align*}
For more details on this I would suggest reading [Quantum Information Processing with Finite Resources](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.00233). The SDP above is equation 6.37 in the linked book. From this you should be able to write the smooth min-entropy in CVX.

Comment: Hi, I have a quick follow-up question to that, as I am dealing with a similar problem. I do not understand why there appear $\rho_{ABC}$ with and without tilde. According to the book, they denote with tilde the density matrices that achieve the extremum. But what about the rho without tilde? 

How do I know the $\rho$ that attains the extremum? Isn't that what I am actually looking for? Or are both $\sigma_{AB}$ and $\tilde{\rho}_{ABC}$ optimization variables in that problem?

Comment: This is the definition of the smooth min-entropy. You want to compute the smooth min-entropy of some state $\rho_{AB}$ and you do so by optimizing over states close to $\rho_{AB}$ hence $\widetilde{\rho}_{AB}$ is an optimization variables, the other optimization variable $\sigma_B$ is coming from the definition of the min-entropy.