# Semi-definite program for conditional smooth max-entropy

Tags: density-matrix, entropy, semidefinite-programming, max-entropy

I am aware of a SDP formulation for *smooth min-entropy*: [question link.](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12746/semi-definite-program-for-smooth-min-entropy) That program for smooth min-entropy was found in this book by Tomachiel: [page 91.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.00233.pdf) However, I am yet to come across a semi-definite formulation for smooth max-entropy. There is however, a formulation for the non-smoothed version of max-entropy, found in this link: [page 4, lemma 8.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.5231.pdf) Here is the detailed program for a bipartite density operator $\rho_{AB}$, $2^{H_{\text{max}}(A|B)_\rho}$ =
$$
\text{minimize }\lambda \\
\text{subject to} \\
Z_{AB} \otimes \mathbb{I} \ge \rho_{ABC} \\
\lambda \mathbb{I}_B \ge \text{tr}_A [Z_{AB}] \\
Z_{AB} \ge 0 \\
\lambda \ge 0
$$

Where $Z_{AB}$ runs over all positive semi-definite operators in $\mathcal{H}_{AB}$, $\lambda$ is a real number. The smooth max-entropy is then:
$$
H^{\epsilon}_{\text{max}}(A|B)ρ := \underset{\rho'_{AB} \in \mathcal{B}^\epsilon (\rho_{AB})}{\min}H_{\text{max}}(A|B)_{\rho'}
$$
i.e., just the minimum over all bipartite operators which are at most $\epsilon$ distance away from $\rho_{AB}$. But the primal or dual SDP formulation for the smooth version of max-entropy was not found anywhere. Is there one? How could I transform it into a smooth version? TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can formulate the smooth max-entropy as an SDP. The author of the book you linked notes this when they explain how to derive the SDP for the smooth min-entropy that you reference on page 91.

In particular they say that the smoothing constraint $\tilde{\rho}_{AB} \in B^\epsilon(\rho_{AB})$ can be reformulated as the triple of constraints
$$
\mathrm{Tr}[\tilde\rho_{ABC} \rho_{ABC}] \geq 1- \epsilon^2~\\
\mathrm{Tr}[\tilde\rho_{ABC}] \leq 1 ~\\
\tilde \rho_{ABC} \geq 0
$$
where $\rho_{ABC}$ is any purification of $\rho_{AB}$.

Now we can incorporate these extra constraints with the SDP formulation of $H_{\max}(A|B)$. In particular
$$
\begin{aligned}
2^{H^\epsilon_{\max}(A|B)_\rho} &= \min_{\tilde{\rho}_{AB} \in B^\epsilon(\rho_{AB})} 2^{H_{\max}(A|B)_{\tilde\rho}} \\
&= \min_{\tilde{\rho}_{AB} \in B^\epsilon(\rho_{AB})}\min \lambda \\
&\qquad\mathrm{s.t.} \quad Z_{AB} \otimes I_C \geq \tilde\rho_{ABC} \\
&\qquad \qquad \lambda I_B \geq \mathrm{Tr}_A[Z_{AB}] \\
&\qquad\qquad Z_{AB} \geq 0, \quad \lambda \geq 0 \\
&= \,\,\,\min \quad\lambda \\
&\qquad\mathrm{s.t.} \quad Z_{AB} \otimes I_C \geq \tilde\rho_{ABC} \\
&\qquad \qquad \lambda I_B \geq \mathrm{Tr}_A[Z_{AB}] \\
&\qquad \qquad \mathrm{Tr}[\tilde\rho_{ABC} \rho_{ABC}] \geq 1- \epsilon^2~\\
&\qquad \qquad \mathrm{Tr}[\tilde\rho_{ABC}] \leq 1 ~\\
&\qquad\qquad \rho_{ABC} \geq 0, \quad Z_{AB} \geq 0, \quad \lambda \geq 0 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: awesome! thanks a lot @Rammus.